# Achieving Clickable views with both Parent and Child

Tags: android, button, layout, focus

I have a `Relativelayout` that is clickable.  I have an element inside it (an `ImageButton`) that I also want to be clickable.

The layout was clickable just fine until I added the `ImageButton`; now only that is clickable.

I have tried all combinations of `focusable` and `focusableInTouchMode` = `true` and `false` in both elements  (I tried only in `xml` layout).  How can I make them BOTH clickable?

My code; note this is inside a `ListView` and each row has this;  there is a non-clickable `LinearLayout` surrounding this:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/row_selector"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

   // several TextViews edited out 

   <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibMenu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@color/row_overflow_state"
            android:contentDescription="menu"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_overflow" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this to your parent

```
android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
```

if used this then don't use the following otherwise you will get *stuck overflow exception*

what about setting this to your child

```
android:duplicateParentState="true"
```

Comment: I tired this and it does not work;  though I have removed all instances of `focusable` in both parent and child.   I will add more code to the question.

Comment: @KickingLettuce you want to generate click event for both Relative layout and button or only one event

Comment: Using only this `android:duplicateParentState="true"` makes BOTH items not clickable now.

Comment: use it addStatesFromChild to parent it accepts the child states

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:descendantsFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on the
RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem. I had a rectangular view which had to receive clicks for some other functionality, as well as an `ImageView` inside the rectangle, had to receive clicks for some other functionality.

Used `Relative Layout` for this purpose where `Relative Layout` was `clickable=true` and having the property

```
android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
```

which means that the layout will receive focus only if none of its descendants want.

So parent, as well as the child, was clickable for two different functionalities.